# SEM using Mplus: Indirect Effects Interpretation and how to report

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

I need some help with the model I created, please see the pic.
As you can see, there are quite a few mediators in the model.

[image]

Below is the indirect and total effects I'm getting. However, I'm wondering how should I report it in APA format in a research paper.
[image]

In addition, is there a way to tease the indirect effects apart to know the mediation effect one at a time?

The last question: why my specific indirect 1 was insignificant in terms of p-value, but the CI actually didn't include 0 in between (see below)? Should I consider it significant or not?
[image]

Thank you for helping out!

Comment: Did you use bootstrap for the CIs?

Comment: Yes, I did. The indirect effects you saw actually were after I used bootstrap.